# Ошибка 403, если в URI содержится символ ":"

Tags: php, laravel, apache, openserver

Так сложилось, что мне в моем веб-приложении (php + Laravel 5.8) нужно обрабатывать маршрут который содержит символ ":" (httt://example.ru/test:sub). Уйди от этого символа возможности нет. Проект работает на хостинге под asp.net, и там все отлично отрабатывает. Когда я его разворачиваю локально, мой OpenServer (Apache) наотрез отказывается принимать такой uri и возвращает 403 ошибку.

Так все работает и локально и на хостинге:

```
Route::get('/testsub', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

Так работает только на хостинге, локально - 403 ошибка:

```
Route::get('/test:sub', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

На удаленном хостинге файл web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Локально .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Прошу, помогите указать на ошибку. Очень нужно работать с этим проектом локально, т.к. работы очень много.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache под Windows не разрешает использовать двоеточие в первой части пути (в Linux такой проблемы нет)

Если это приемлемо, попробуйте добавить еще один уровень вложенности:

```
Route::get('/subdir/test:sub', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

Или используйте сервер PHP вместо апача:

```
php artisan serve
```

после запуска этой команды сайт будет доступен по 
http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Спасибо большое! Шикарно-качественный ответ. Оба варианта работают. Если бы мог, поставил десятки плюсов.